# Out of memory when running app with Emulator on Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I run my app on Emulator of Android Studio 4.1.1 with exception:

```
 ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/zone.cc: 94: error: Out of memory.
version=2.10.4 (stable) (Wed Nov 11 13:35:58 2020 +0100) on "windows_x64"
pid=19872, thread=13300, isolate_group=main(000001D8CE0F0B60), isolate=main(000001D8CE117730)
isolate_instructions=7ff70550f230, vm_instructions=7ff70550f240
  pc 0x00007ff7056a00ec fp 0x0000005f752fdff0 Unknown symbol
-- End of DumpStackTrace
```

- `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.49.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

- I can run my app with real device.

Comment: It is what it states. The emulator runs outta memory. The same happened to me. Just wipe the emulator data. Go to `Settings -> System -> Advanced -> Reset options -> Factory Reset`. If it pops up often, ya might wanna increase your emulator storage.

Comment: I can't find "Settings -> System -> Advanced -> Reset options -> Factory Reset". Where's it in Android Studio?

Comment: Ohh... I told you how to do it from the emulator, lol. In android studio, go to `AVD Manager` and go to `Actions` on your device. In the drop down menu, click `Wipe data`